Create a custom Handler Class for Canvas in JavaFX
I am making a Java Paint application using JavaFX. I do not want to have a spaghetti controller, so I want to implement methods for handling Canvas in a separate Class. I am a bit lost on EventHandlers.
I have tried

Creating a CanvasHandler class that extends EventHandler or MouseEvent
I do not know how to that initialize it and add it to the Controller.

Creating CustomCanvas that extends Canvas and Implement MouseEvent
Again, nothing happens after running the app, for I do not know how to link the handler to the
class.
Here is the code from Controller that I want to add to a separate Class:


  canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        x1 = e.getX();
                        y1 = e.getY();
                        switch (tool) {
                            case "Brush":
                                drawing.setLineWidth(currentSize);
                                drawing.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
                                drawing.beginPath();
                                drawing.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
                                drawing.moveTo(x1, y1);
                                break;
                            case "Eraser":
                                drawing.clearRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentSize, currentSize);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                switch (tool) {
                    case "Brush":
                        dragged = true;
                        drawing.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        drawing.stroke();
                        break;
                    case "Eraser":
                        drawing.clearRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentSize, currentSize);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                switch (tool) {
                    case "Brush":
                        drawing.closePath();
                        if (!dragged) {

                            drawing.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
                            drawing.fillOval(x1, y1, currentSize + 2, currentSize + 2);
                        }
                        dragged = false;
                        break;
                    case "Eraser":
                        drawing.clearRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentSize, currentSize);
                        break;
                    case "Rectangle":
                        UI.createShape(e, x1, y1, colorPicker, tool);
                        break;
                    case "Oval":
                        UI.createShape(e, x1, y1, colorPicker, tool);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });



There is no real need to subclass anything here. Just create a standalone controller class, instantiate it, and then where you create the UI you can do canvas.setMousePressed(e -> controller.handlePress(…)). Or create a method in the controller, say public void install(Node node) { … } to do the event handler registration and just do controller.install(canvas). It’s not really clear where you’re stuck.

Simple paint app, in case that helps.

Many uses of JavaFX APIs are better served through use of aggregation and composition vs inheritance.  Indeed, numerous key classes in the JavaFX hierarchy are final by design, so that developers will not use inheritance with them, or the implementations have final private fields in them making subclassing difficult or pointless, or refer to private API in com.sun packages not exposed in the public module API.
